# Detecting active tab is a new tab in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Until recently it was possible, in a chrome extension, to know if the current tab was a new tab by checking if the tab url was "chrome://newtab/" however since the last update it seems that the new tab url is something like "https://www.google.[...]/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&[...]".

Is there a robust way to find if the active tab is newtab ? (I don't consider catching newtab event or having a superficial look at the url shape as robust)

Comment: Please show your code. I cannot reproduce your problem in Chrome 32.0.1667.0 (Canary Aura, Windows). I've created a dummy extension with the `<all_urls>` and `tabs` permissions, and read the current URL in the `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` event, which showed "chrome://newtab/".

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm doing the exact same thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Use `activeTab.url == "chrome://newtab/"`

At least in Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit), to check if the current/active tab is a new tab, you can still do:

```
activeTab.url == "chrome://newtab/"
```

Maybe you have another extension or a configuration setting where it's defaulting your new tabs to a certain URL.